# How to flat query result?

Tags: graphql

With a sample make it easy understand, with https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/

query the viewer info:

```
query {
  viewer {
    followers {
      totalCount
    }
    following {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

the result is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "followers": {
        "totalCount": 131
      },
      "following": {
        "totalCount": 28
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what I want is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "followersCount" 131,
      "followingCount": 28
    }
  }
}
```

so does GraphQL support this ? and how to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GraphQL doesn't support this type of data flattening.
You must change the data structure in your code or work with the returned data structure.

---

**EDIT:** I just came across [this repository (graphql-lodash)](https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-lodash) that could help you achieve what you want.