# bypass "nested" objects in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I have next gql fragment:

```
fragment PropertyInformationStateFragment on Property{
    property_state{
      data{
        attributes{
          state
          description
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and here is example of data returned:

```
"property_state": {
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "state": "Tres bon état",
      "description": "Tres bon état du bien immobilier"
    }
  }
}
```

Do somebody knows how to "bypass" this `data` and `attributes` objects?

**Data returned I expect:**

```
"property_state": {
  "state": "blabla",
  "description": "blabla"
}
```

*What should I do?*

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534644/how-to-flat-query-result

Comment: Yes, but there is no correct answer (solution) to the topic you shared. And the topic was created 5 years ago, maybe somebody has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing changed in these 5 years. There are still no ways to do it and I don't think it will have in the future. Sorry about that.

It is because GraphQL only allows client to define which fields to be included in the response or changing the field name but not allow  change the response structure. Your query must following the type structure defined by the server. The server can only return you the data in this defined structure but what you are asking now is to return the data in a total different structure.

What you can do is to convert it to the structure that you want manually in the client side which should be a piece of cake.